# How can I show my scheduled posts in Google Calendar?

Tags: scheduled-posts

I typically schedule posts well in advance before they get published. At times I can have as many as 5-10 scheduled posts set to be published within the coming weeks.

Is there a way to show a calendar with all my scheduled posts? Ideally I would like to see them in Google Calendar.

Comment: I don't think there is handy enough import into Google Calendar. Would WP dashboard widget work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not Google Calendar, but the [Editorial Calendar](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/editorial-calendar/) plugin works really nicely.

[image: Screenshot of Editorial Calendar plugin borrowed from the plugins directory]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this iCal plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ical-feeds/) to generate an iCalendar file which you can subscribe to in Google Calendar. See [instructions in for subscribing to an iCal link](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37100).

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was a Zapier Integration, linking Wordpress and Google Calendar. The main thing is to remember to tell the Zap that you make, to only pull in Wordpress posts with Post Status = "Scheduled". You are going to have to type that word "Scheduled" in manually, under the list of Wordpress Post Statuses that Zapier will present. This is because Zapier doesn't automatically list "Scheduled" as a post status on WordPress. With that, it will work well.